# C# MonthCalendar control Get date under cursor

Tags: c#, .net, monthcalendar

Is there a way to get the date under the cursor on the MonthCalendar control? I'd like to collect this on right click to pass into a dialog. Right clicking doesn't seem to trigger it's click event. I tried overloading the MouseDown event, but that didn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, MonthCalendar has its own context menu so the right-button click event is disabled.  Surgery is required to re-enable it.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyCalendar : MonthCalendar {
    public event MouseEventHandler RightClick;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x205) {   // Trap WM_RBUTTONUP
            var handler = RightClick;
            if (handler != null) {
                var pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
                var me = new MouseEventArgs((MouseButtons)m.WParam.ToInt32(), 1, pos.x, pos.y, 0);
                handler(this, me);
            }
            this.Capture = false;
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

You now have a RightClick event that you can subscribe.  Something similar to this:

```
    private void myCalendar1_RightClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var hit = myCalendar1.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (hit.HitArea == MonthCalendar.HitArea.Date) {
            var dt = hit.Time;
            MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString());   // Display your context menu here
        }
    }
```

Comment: That worked great. Thank you. :) Should have thought of it myself.

Answer (score 0):

if you want capture right click, please try this

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
  {

  }
}
```

more info can be found here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx